# Enabling Amazon SSL for single instance

Tags: apache, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have configured SSL for our amazon EC2 server. I have configured /etc/apache2/ports.conf and /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl (to listen 443) with the certificate paths and restarted the server. I am unable to view the secured link here: https://ec2-54-217-244-0.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Should I add HTTPS to Inbound in Security groups?

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, you should make sure you have 443 open to this host in the security group and via iptables if you're using it. You can always test locally to see if it works. `curl https://localhost`

Comment: Thanks Ben, if I make a change though AWS Console (adding the https port to inbound list), will it affect the live site by any chance? Sorry, if this is a stupid question, I am very new to AWS..

Comment: The live site on port 80? No, it won't affect it. You can just add 443 and it will be open too.

Comment: @SudhamshaReddy You just deleted a question. The problem is most likely console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default Security Group denies all traffic to the Instances.  If you want to access your Apache server on HTTPS, you will need to add a rule to your Security group to explicitly authorise TCP 443 traffic.

More details are available in the documentation : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules

Comment: Thanks for that! I added that to Security group. But when I go visit the https site, it's blank: https://www.team-alpha.ie . Can you please help me if I am doing anything wrong!

Comment: I tried 'curl -v https://www.team-alpha.ie/' and it said'Connection refused' Are you sure your server is on ?  When you ssh connect to the instance and type 'netstat -tnlp | grep 443' do you have something ?

Comment: I have nothing for the command, I tried netstat -tnlp and got below:
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)

Comment: Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22         :::*                    LISTEN  -

Comment: This shows you have no process listening on port 443. (only 80, 22, 3306 and 9000)  Double check your Apache configuration to be sure it is configured correctly